# How to fix error: Error creating bean with name 'characterController'

Tags: java, spring

have this error with I trying run my app
I don't understand what should I try to put the app in the debug mode and I could not know why it is the error

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2021-05-30 14:45:05.385[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m15550[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'characterController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'characterService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'characterServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'characterRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ICharacterRepository' defined in com.backend.API.repository.ICharacterRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Character
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:337) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1336) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1325) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.backend.API.ApiApplication.main(ApiApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'characterServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'characterRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ICharacterRepository' defined in com.backend.API.repository.ICharacterRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Character
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ICharacterRepository' defined in com.backend.API.repository.ICharacterRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Character
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Character
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:75) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:228) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:161) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:72) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:319) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/characters")
public class CharacterController {
    
    @Autowired
    private ICharacterService characterService;
    
    
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<CustomCharacter>> characters(){
        return ResponseEntity.status(Response.SC_OK).body(this.characterService.getAll());
    }
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Character> createPersonaje(@RequestBody Character ch) {
        Character p = this.characterService.save(ch);
        return new ResponseEntity<Character>(p, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface ICharacterRepository extends JpaRepository<Character, Long>{
    
    /* crea un nuevo objeto a partir del objeto Personaje pero solo
     * se queda con los campos deseados.
     */
    @Query("SELECT NEW com.backend.API.entity.CustomCharacter(c.name, c.image) FROM Character c")
    public List<CustomCharacter> getAll();
    
}
```

Services:

```
@Service
public interface ICharacterService {
    
    public List<CustomCharacter> getAll();
    
    public Character findById(long id);
    
    public Character save(Character ch);

}




@Service
public class CharacterServiceImpl implements ICharacterService{
    
    @Autowired
    private ICharacterRepository characterRepository;
    
    

    @Override
    public List<CustomCharacter> getAll() {
        return this.characterRepository.getAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Character findById(long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Character save(Character ch) {
        return this.characterRepository.save(ch);
    }
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Character {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String image;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String history;
    
    
    public Character(long id, String image, String name, int age, String history) {
        this.image = image;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.history = history;
    }
    
    public Character() {
        
    }
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
     @JoinTable(
       name = "participa",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FK_CHARACTER", nullable = false),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="FK_SERIE", nullable = false))
     private List<Serie> series;
```

**Why it's?
I was looking for a solution and I haven't found anything, any help?
I thought the problem was the LONG but that's okay**

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is within the error

> nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class **java.lang.Character**

You are trying to use java.lang.Character instead of your model "Character".
Try importing it with yourpackage.Character or I would prefer renaming the Character
to something else.